# How do I get a table after a hyperlink?

Tags: jquery

A table isn't a sibling to a hyperlink is it?
I have:

```
<a href="JavaScript:;">Show me the table</a>
<table class="hidden">
...
</table>
```

Q: What jQuery selector do I use to get the table following the anchor tag?

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $(this).something.slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest *not* assuming your table will always be adjacent. It may be right now, but if you need to move it for some reason your code will break.

Save yourself some trouble and store an identifier for the table in the anchor element. One option is to use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) to store the selector.

```
<a href="#" data-target-table="#table1">Show me the table</a>
<table id="table1" class="hidden">
    ...
</table>
```

and get it using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $table = $($this.data('targetTable'));
    $table.something.slideDown();
});
```

An alternative is to have a common class on each element and use that to select the table.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You might either use .next() or .siblings() to access an element at the same level in the DOM.

So in your example you could use:

```
 $('a').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('table').slideDown();
 });
```

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that siblings were all the same type of element, like li or td.

Comment: That's definitely one use case for .siblings(), but it's more general than that. Even on http://api.jquery.com/siblings/ they use it for a paragraph tag.

Comment: Yes, but only sibling paragraphs.